# "Project file changed" issue in PhpStorm during working remotely

Tags: connection, phpstorm, mount, cifs

I have CIFS mounted folder on my PC, where houses a PHP project.
And very often dialog box appears with the message:

> Project file /path/to/mounted/directory/.idea/workspace.xml" has been
>   changed externally. It is recommended to reload project for changes to
>   take effect.

I don't make any changes in this file, but PhpStorm thinks sometimes that file was changed and shows this dialog.

This directory mounts on system startup, and this is the corresponding fstab string:

```
//host/path /media/server cifs _netdev,credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0
```

This mount settings I've made today. Before that the directory was mounted through sshfs and all was OK without this annoying dialog box.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Quite possible that file timestamp (modification time) gets reported slightly different (quite often happens with SAMBA shares). Dig in this direction for now. Check comments in this ticket -- maybe you will find some instructions/advices: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88884

Comment: Maybethis one: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-88884#comment=27-474231 : "I fixed it by adding `cache=none` to my `fstab` options."

Comment: @LazyOne, thank you a lot, this ticket about the same problem, I'll try  this solution later. Now I've reverted changes to sshfs and the dialog box has stopped to appears. I wonder is there any disadvantages in using sshfs instead of cifs? Is it just a processor overhead because of encryption/decryption?

Comment: No clue, sorry -- not a Linux user.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a current solution, I hope that this can help everyone that is encountering this issue.

```
**Go** to Settings (File->Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S) ) 
and reach Appearance & Behavior-> System Settings
```

**uncheck all 4 options of Synchronization.**

This is how I managed to fix this problem, now I don't have to 
reverse commit,
No dialog box that the project has been modified externally and no workspace.xml popping up in SourceTree.